# Change User Role After Certain Number of Days | Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am two types of User

> Reader: Can Read Books
>
> Subscriber: Cannot Reed Books

In my user table, I have trialto column, which adds 7days to the date which the email is verified.

So my problem is to fire an event or a function that checks the trialto column when the trialto column equals to now().

I am building a Laravel Application where when the user signup and verifies his email, he is given a Reader Role as trial by Default, but after 7 days it reverts back to Subscriber if the User didn't subscribe.

I don't have the idea of how to go about this, I am thinking Laravel Scheduling can help in fixing this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan - you can write your own console command, and run it once a day, inside command just check creation time and update status

Comment: Opinion-based..

Comment: @V-K, I think there should a way to schedule it. Without running command once a day. I don't think this approach is effective.

Comment: Usually, cron is used for such tasks (Console command in laravel is the same), and I don't know the better way. The only thing you can change - is cron frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling), and save in the model the `suscripted_date`. With this task, you can make Laravel check for condition after certain lapse of time.

Answer (score 0):

I would just check the `trialto` date when showing content and not set trial users as Readers:

```php
class User 
{
    public function isSubscriber() 
    {
        return $this->role === 'Reader' || $this->trialto->isFuture();
    }
}
```